# Pandas Dataframe: how to add column with number of occurrences in other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to following df:

```
Col1    Col2
test    Something
test2   Something
test3   Something
test    Something
test2   Something
test5   Something
```

I want to get

```
Col1    Col2          Occur
test    Something     2
test2   Something     2
test3   Something     1
test    Something     2
test2   Something     2
test5   Something     1
```

I've tried to use:

```
df["Occur"] = df["Col1"].value_counts()
```

But it didn't help. I've got Occur column full of 'NaN'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on 'col1' and then apply [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on `Col2` to return a Series with its index aligned to the original df so you can add it as a column:

```
In [3]:
df['Occur'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
df

Out[3]:
    Col1       Col2 Occur
0   test  Something     2
1  test2  Something     2
2  test3  Something     1
3   test  Something     2
4  test2  Something     2
5  test5  Something     1
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `GroupBy` + `transform` with `size`:

```
df['Occur'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].transform('size')

print(df)

    Col1       Col2  Occur
0   test  Something      2
1  test2  Something      2
2  test3  Something      1
3   test  Something      2
4  test2  Something      2
5  test5  Something      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the other answers to work when I want to retain more columns than just the two columns Col1 and Col2. Below works well for me with any number of other columns retained.

```
df['Occur'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: (df['Col1'] == x).sum())
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the behaviour implied in this answer. Assigning a series to `df['Occur']` as in the other answers does not impact other columns. Further, using `lambda` + manual sums with a Python-level `apply` loop will generally be inefficient versus `transform` + vectorised functionality.